# Working on Pydev - Eclipse; error on PyUnit

Tags: eclipse, windows, pydev

I'm having some trouble running PyUnit on Eclipse. I made a couple of tests, but the PyUnit window doesn't show anything, neither the console one.

In the Error Log, I get these messages:

> *Error creating python process - exited before creating sockets - exitValue = (-1073741515)
>
> *org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error creating python process - exited before creating sockets - exitValue = (-1073741515)
>
> *Error when getting assign completions for:unittest.case
>
> *Error while getting info for module:_ _builtin__. Project: P/ChainList

I'm doing these right clicking the module of testing > Run as > Python unit-test. These appear usually repeated themselves several times. I don't know if something is missing in the config (I left the PyUnit preference as default)
I also tried with CTRL+F9 but nothing happens

Running Windows 7; and Python, Eclipse and Pydev run from an external drive

If you need some more data, please let me know

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The messages in your error log all point to having issues preventing the shell that PyDev launches for code-completion purposes from working properly...

Can you post the full trace?

Google says that the error -1073741515 means that some dll was not found (so, it may be an issue in the Python installation or in the PATH configuration)... Do things work properly if you launch things in a shell? (outside Eclipse)

Comment: I coudln't say...i mean, this is the first time i run Python on Eclipse (i only used Java before) so i don't know. The code seems to work inside, but i didn't try it ouside (i wouldn't know how, neither...i'm just starting to program in University; and this is for one of the subjects)...Maybe i'm missing something?? I got installed in the drive the Eclipse, the Pydev plugin, Python; and then i config the python.exe path on the pydev...then i started to code, and didn't do anything else

Comment: I already was able to work it out, at least for now...i got the pyhton installed on the external drive, but seems it needs some kind of reg writing or something like that; so i re-installed python in the other machines, and at least for now the pyunit is working. Thanks